# Data structure for dynamically changing n-length sequence with longest subsequence length query

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

I need to design a data structure for holding `n`-length sequences, with the following methods:

- `increasing()` - returns length of the longest increasing sub-sequence
- `change(i, x)` - adds x to i-th element of the sequence

Intuitively, this sounds like something solvable with some kind of interval tree. But I have no idea how to think of that.

I'm wondering how to use the fact, that we completely don't need to know how this sub-sequence looks like, we only need its length...

Maybe this is something that can be used, but I'm pretty much stuck at this point.

Comment: Did you mean a contiguous subsequence?

Comment: No, I meant a general subsequence, I think contiguous case is much simpler.

Comment: I assumed as much, but I wanted to be sure before trying to make heads or tails of valdem's answer

Comment: So if I understand you correctly, it should a variable number of variable-length sequences. Each sequence in this data structure may be in any order.
`increasing()` returns the longest increasing sub-sequence, which may be an entire sequence or may be a portion of one.
'change(i,x)' **appends** (?) `x` to the `i`th subsequence?

So, are there a constant number of sequences? Or is there another operation to create a new empty sequence?

Comment: Or.. reading it again, the data structure holds a **single** variable length sequence and `change(i,x)` **inserts** `x` at the `i`th position in the single sequence? Which is the behavior you are going for?

Comment: `change(i, x)` changes single variable from n-length sequence (e.g. of numbers, something like a[i]+=x)
`increasing()` returns length of the greatest length SUBSEQENCE contained in the sequence

Comment: aha! So it has constant length `n`, and `change(i,x)` adds `x` to the `i`th position of the sequence. Got it. Can `x` be negative?

Comment: `n` is not a constant, this is a variable on which we do our asymptotic analysis. `x` can be negative.

Comment: can you give an example of a few calls to your proposed methods and what you want to get back as a response?

Answer (score 2):

**This solves the problem only for contiguous intervals.  It doesn't solve arbitrary subsequences. :-(**

It is possible to implement this with time `O(1)` for interval and `O(log(n))` for `change`.

First of all we'll need a heap for all of the current intervals, with the largest on top.  Finding the longest interval is just a question of looking on the top of the heap.

Next we need a bunch of information for each of our `n` slots.

```
value: Current value in this slot
interval_start: Where the interval containing this point starts
interval_end: Where the interval containing this point ends
heap_index: Where to find this interval in the heap NOTE: Heap operations MUST maintain this!
```

And now the clever trick!  We **always** store the value for each slot.  But we **only** store the interval information for an interval at the point in the interval whose index is divisible by the highest power of 2.  There is always only one such point for any interval, so storing/modifying this is very little work.

Then to figure out what interval a given position in the array currently falls in, we have to look at all of the neighbors that are increasing powers of 2 until we find the last one with our value.  So, for instance, position `13`'s information might be found in any of the positions `0, 8, 12, 13, 14, 16, 32, 64, ....`  (And we'll take the first interval we find it in in the list `0, ..., 64, 32, 16, 8, 12, 14, 13`.)  This is a search of a `O(log(n))` list so is `O(log(n))` work.

Now how do we implement `change`?

1. Update value.
2. Figure out what interval we were in, and whether we were at an interval boundary.
3. If intervals got changed, remove the old ones from the heap.  (We may remove 0, 1 or 2)
4. If intervals got change, insert the new ones into the heap.  (We may insert 0, 1, or 2)

That update is very complex, but it is a fixed number of `O(log(n))` operations and so should be `O(log(n))`.

Comment: I think this is looking for *contiguous* subsequences, like valdem's answer but unlike the question.

Answer (score 1):

LIS can be solved with tree, but there is another implementation with dynamic programming, which is faster than recursive tree.
This is a simple implementation in C++.

```cpp
class LIS {
    private vector<int> seq ;
    public LIS(vector<int> _seq) {seq = _seq ;}
    public int increasing() {
        int i, j ;
        vector<int> lengths ;
        lengths.resize(seq.size()) ;
        for(i=0;i<seq.size();i++) lengths[i] = 1 ;

        for(i=1;i<seq.size();i++) {
            for(j=0;j<i;j++) {
                if( seq[i] > seq[j] && lengths[i] < lengths[j]+1 ) {
                    lengths[i] = lengths[j] + 1 ;
                }
            }
        }

        int mxx = 0 ;
        for(i=0;i<seq.size();i++)
            mxx = mxx < lengths[i] ? lengths[i] : mxx ;

        return mxx ;
    }

    public void change(i, x) {
        seq[i] += x ;
    }

}
```

Comment: This doesn't look like the most efficient solution. In an ideal solution, when you're asking for `increasing()`, you won't solve the problem from scratch every time...

Comment: Rather, that information should be easily available somehow, using nontrivial work that `change()` would do every time it's called.

Comment: @qiubit As you didn't specify the constrains for preprocessing time, update time and query time, it is a little bit unfair to say now, that this algorithm is too slow.

Answer (score 1):

I try to explain my idea. It can be a bit simpler than implementing interval tree, and should give desirable complexity - O(1) for increasing(), and O(logS) for change(), where S is sequences count (can be reduced to N in worst cases of course).

At first you need original array. It need to check borders of intervals (I will use word interval as synonym to sequence) after change(). Let it be **A**

At the second you need bidirectional list of intervals. Element of this list should store left and right borders. Every increasing sequence should be presented as separate element of this list and this intervals should go one after another as they presented in **A**. Let this list be **L**. We need to operate pointers on elements, so, I don't know is it possible to do it on iterators with standard container.

At third you need priority queue that stores lengths of all intervals in you array. So, increasing() function can be done with O(1) time. But you need also storing of pointer to node from **L** to lookup intervals. Let this priority queue be **PQ**. More formally you priority queue contains pairs (length of interval, pointer to list node) with comparison only by length.

At forth you need tree, that can retrieve interval borders (or range) for particular element. It can be simply implemented with std::map where key is left border of tree, so with help of map::lower_bound you can find this interval. Value should store pointer to interval in **L**. Let this map be **MP**

And next important thing - List nodes should stores indecies of corresponding element in priority queue. And you shouldn't work with priority queue without connection with link to node from **L** (every swap operation on **PQ** you should update corresponding indecies on **L**).

change(i, x) operation can be looks like this:

1. Find interval, where i located with map. -> you find pointer to corresponding node in **L**. So, you know borders and length of interval
2. Try to understand what actions need to do: nothing, split interval, glue intervals.
3. Do this action on list and map with connection with **PQ**. If you need split interval, remove it from **PQ** (this is not remove-max operation) and then add 2 new elements to **PQ**. Similar if you need to glue intervals, you can remove one from **PQ** and do increase-key to second.

One difficulty is that **PQ** should support removing arbitrary element (by index), so you can't use std::priority_queue, but it is not difficult to implement as I think.

Comment: If I understand correctly, this answer is for *contiguous* subsequences, which is an easier problem.

Comment: Yeah, I tried to parse that answer and it looks like it. What did you mean by "At third you need priority queue that stores lengths of all intervals in you array. So, increasing() function can be done with O(1) time."? As I understand, intervals represent sequences (as you wrote earlier), so on top of the priority queue, there will be length of the longest SEQUENCE, which is not what this problem is about. Or maybe by O(1) you meant something else than `ExtractMax()` operation, correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Yes, sorry for unclear answer. I solved contiguous subsequences problem, maybe because question is unclear for me. By O(1) I meant TakeMax() because we don't want extract Max (remove element from queue)